# How to display the elements of a graph's adjacency list?

Tags: c++, list, stl

I still study c++ and i'd like to ask a little help. I have the following representation of a graph:

```
struct Vertex
{
    list<Vertex*> adj;
    string name;
    Vertex(string str) : name(str) {}
};

class Graph
{
public:
    typedef map<string, Vertex*> vmap;
    vmap vm;
    void AddVertex(const string&);
    void AddEdge(const string& from, const string& to);
};
```

The way i use it:

```
Graph g1;
g1.AddVertex("2");
g1.AddVertex("3");
g1.AddVertex("4");
g1.AddVertex("1");
g1.AddEdge("1", "2");
g1.AddEdge("1", "3");
g1.AddEdge("1", "4");
```

Now i'd like to simply cout the vertices and their connections (if exists any) to check if it's working as i expect. I tried the following way, but i'm getting an error which i'm not fully understand and don't know how it can be fixed:

```
map<string, Vertex*>::iterator itr = g1.vm.begin();
for(itr; itr != g1.vm.end(); itr++)
{
    cout << itr->first << " ";
    list<Vertex*>::iterator li = itr->second->adj.begin();
    for(li; li != itr->second->adj.end(); li++)
    {
        cout << li->name << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

My question is that how can i get the vertices names from that adj list? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post the error?
In the for loop's initialization part (`for(itr; ...`), itr has no meaning. Try removing that as a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that `li` is an iterator of pointers, so you need to de-reference it to access the member `name`:

```
cout << (*li)->name << " ";
```

The reason you didn't need to do this for your top-level iterator, `itr`, is that its an iterator of `std::pair`'s, and thus your `->` access de-referenced the iterator to get at the members of `std::pair`.

@ehudt's answer solves this by using the [c++11 range based `for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loops such that the `->` operator is on `*Vertex` and not `list<Vertex*>::iterator`.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the explanation, that was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to write this would be:

```
for(const auto& vm_pair : g1.vm)
{
    cout << vm_pair.first << " ";
    for (const auto& li : vm_pair.second->adj)
    {
        cout << li->name << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```